# Need help parsing email with no formatting

Tags: c#, email, parsing

Good morning all.

I currently have an email sent to me once a month.  for years the team that receives this email have been manually copying and pasting this into an excel sheet, Which is now taking up more time than it should have ever.

I have been asked to automate the process, And I am having issues, I have tried various methods of parsing and cleaning to get the email to some kind of format that I can turn it into a CSV but without any luck.  If anyone has any idea's on a great way to parse this email I would greatly appreciate it.  I have included an image below,  The format does not change at all, there is up to 1500 of them in one email.  Certain data had to be blacked out due to security. The programming has all been done in C# .net 4.5.

[image: Apple monthly Report]

If any additional information is required please let me know.
Thank you!!

As Requested a plain-text version

http://pastebin.com/uFhAcnem

Comment: Can you paste one as plain-text so we can have a play?

Comment: Its multiple-white-space delimited fields with a ----- row delimiter, whats the issue?

Comment: There is formatting in the text...it follows a pattern. Change the title of your question.

Comment: Updated title, Added a plaintext,  The issue is I need Repair# PO# Dispatch# Serial# Repair Date SN Type Warranty Material# Description Amount Score Total as headers with the relevant information as data.  I have tried to parse it several different ways with no working outcome.

Comment: Try ETL tool. Those  tools can save your time and calories for formatting.

Comment: Looks like fixed column width, fixed format text. Should be quite simple to parse and convert to CSV. What have you tried? What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the format is always like the one in your sample, consider the following code using string.Split with StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries:

```
public static string inputEmail = "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"
  + "Repair #      PO#                                   Dispatch #        Serial #\n"
  + "03018377XXXX  JH103786                              G18646XXXX        C02NN8NAXXXX\n"
  + ""
  + "Repair Date   SN Type                               Warranty\n"
  + "10.03.2015    SP Carry-In Repairs                   APPLE LIMITED WARRANTY\n"
  + ""
  + "Material #    Description                                   Amount   Score       Total\n"
  + "011-0472      SVC, LABOR TIER 2                              25.00   1.36        34.00\n";


private static void Main(string[] args)
{
  string[] parts = inputEmail.Split(new string[] { "  " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
  foreach (string part in parts)
    Console.WriteLine(part.Trim());
}
```

That produces the following output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Repair #
PO#
Dispatch #
Serial #
03018377XXXX
JH103786
G18646XXXX
C02NN8NAXXXX
Repair Date
SN Type
Warranty
10.03.2015
SP Carry-In Repairs
APPLE LIMITED WARRANTY
Material #
Description
Amount
Score
Total
011-0472
SVC, LABOR TIER 2
25.00
1.36
34.00
```

That should be easy to parse (you just hold a counter for lines, reset the counter if ----- line is detected and then you know that line 5 is Repair number, line 6 is PO number ...).

Comment: This is perfect and I am not sure why I did not think of it! Thank you Wapac!!

Answer (score 0):

Read the text line by line

If you find the starting token (line starts with "Repair #") then parse this line into its fixed fields.

From this line you know the next 7 lines with fixed format:

so read 7 next lines and parse them into their respective fixed field.

Start over until end of file

Add a lot of checking and error handling.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm the founder of mailparser.io

You can do the parsing with our software http://mailparser.io. We offer text filters which are able to extract repeating text blocks and split them up into separate fields. Once parsed, you can download the data as a CSV or send it to another web application with webhooks.

Let me know if you want to try out the free trial and I'll help you with the setup.